# Get Webpage to be Absolute

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't make my webpage absolute. When I reposition my webpage the "Name1" & "Name2" & "select box" moves around. I want to be able to resize the browser and keep the size so the text and select box won't collide. Thanks

Below are the codes:

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0 border: 0
}
#TL {
    background: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 5%;
    right: 0%;
    bottom: 0%
}
#TRR {
    background: 0;
    top: 25%;
    left: 30%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0%
}
```

**Html:**

```
    <div id="TL">
    <h2>Name1</h2>
    <select name="select1" id="select1" size="4" multiple>
        <option value="1">Fruit</option>
        <option value="2">Animal</option>
        <option value="3">Bird</option>
        <option value="4">Car</option>
    </select>

    </div>

    <div id="TL">   
    <h2>Name2</h2>
    <select name="select2" id="select2" size="4" multiple>
        <option value="1">Banana</option>
        <option value="1">Apple</option>
        <option value="1">Orange</option>
        <option value="2">Wolf</option>
        <option value="2">Fox</option>
        <option value="2">Bear</option>
        <option value="3">Eagle</option>
        <option value="3">Hawk</option>
        <option value="4">BWM
            <option>
    </select>
          <input type="button" id="button" value="Execute" />
            <div id="wrapper"></div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
  $("#select1").change(function() { 
    if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
        /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
        $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
        } 
    var id = $(this).val();

        console.log(id);


        var options = $(this).data('options').filter(

        function () {
            return $.inArray(this.value, id) > -1
        });
        $('#select2').html(options);
    });

    $('#button').click(function() {
        var values = [];

         $('#select1 option:selected').each(function() {
            values.push($(this).text());
        });
        $('#select2 option:selected').each(function() {
            values.push($(this).text());
        });
        $("#wrapper").html(values.join(", "));
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use percentage widths or positions, things will adjust to the size of your window (or container).

To fix the size and position, use fixed units like pixels eg.

```
#TL {
  width: 400px;
}
```

Also causing a problem right now is that you have defined `<div id="TL">` twice - probably one of them is supposed to be TR. So currently they're both getting the same fixed position.

You generally don't need to use fixed positions just to keep things from moving when you resize. Just using a fixed width container will do the job - but of course, it depends on the layout you're trying to achieve.